# gdm.service preventing boot

Tags: boot, gdm, troubleshooting, 23.10

> [image: 1]

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 23.10. I've tried every suggestion in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387469/boot-hangs-when-starting-gdm-service) as well as many others online, but I cannot get back into the Ubuntu GUI/GNOME desktop environment. I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 desktop.

Comment: It's best if you're specific; ie. you're using Ubuntu 23.10 instead of a *vague* term like *latest* version. Your picture seems to me to show gdm.service actually started correctly (ie. it wasn't *Starting* but *Started*); then an issue occurred.

Comment: is there a way to check if gdm.service is causing the problem? or any other way i could determine the cause

Comment: I opened another tty and can confirm that gdm service fails to start.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced with this issue and after trying different options, I finally could solve the issue by doing the following steps:

- While being stuck in the page you shared the image, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to get into another tty.
- Provide user/pass and login to your account
- Run `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
- To verify the solution, run `startx`. If successful, you can restart the system and expect the gdm can work properly.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!