How do I fix amdgpu on Ubuntu 22.04?
I have a Lenovo Yoga 6, AMD Ryzen 7 5700 U, with AMD Radeon Integrated graphics. I have just installed Ubuntu on my laptop and everything was working properly until I updated and upgraded the system. I rebooted after that, and after doing that I started to get this error:

Since I cannot access my drive, I've been booting from my flash drive, hoping I could find a firmware or something that could be missing.
I'd like to know if someone has a workaround for this, and how I can get it done booting from my flash drive.

The picture is cut off top and bottom but in the center it shows the GPU has failed. You can boot from live media and edit the grub file on the hard drive and add the nomodeset option. This web site explains the command https://askubuntu.com/tags/nomodeset/info

I don't see an error; only OK and notices about Direct Rendering Manager. Errors are always in RED

The 1st line means --hibernation is not working--. Probably benign and NOT part of your problem. FIRST thing to do: pick the previous kernel from GRUB and see if that works. If it does try to see if journalctl or a log file shows an issue to solve.

It is in blue and says generic failure

Thank you for commenting. I followed the instructions on the post you gave me, however, after I made the change to "nomodeset" tried to continue with the boot, but got stuck on the same screen with the "[ ok ]". I don't see the errors now, but still it does not continue.

This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387469/boot-hangs-when-starting-gdm-service

@amar it worked!
